# build failed for android - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtEUd.png)I have been developing an app getting list of wifi devices using flutter package: flutter_nearby_connection but it is showing that "Build Failed With an Exception",but there is no error or warning showing in code what is  the issue how can i resolve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cj7I.png)

code : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections/example

Comment: Looks like theres a problem with your `build.gradle` file on line 30. Can you post that file so we can see it

Comment: Check it now Updated

Comment: I don't see an issue with build.gradle that looks like any other build.gradle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

What Is Your Gradle Version?If it's 6.7 then downgrade it to 6.5